# How to do Error-handling for JWT in API Manager (apim)

Tags: api, jwt, ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I have done JWT Validation in all my API Services. And now I want to create an Error-Handling setup for the API Services using JWT. I have successfully established the error-handling setup when the Authorization token (JWT access token) is null or empty and doesn't match its length. And now I want to create an error handling setup to check if the JWt Token is same as the one that is generated. I am doing this since I want to customize the JWT Error Messages.

Here is a screenshot of the existing Error Handling:

[image: Error-Handling in an API Service]

Comment: Why do you need to check the length of the token or compare it to the original one you generated? Do you store all tokens on server side? You only need to validate the token with it's signature and your key/secret.

Comment: Yes jps, its true. But the error that i get on invalid JWT , is "JWT Validation failed". I want to customize this error. And i also want to know how to obtain the original correct jwt and my jwt that i entered.